# Java SwingWorker locks up GUI

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

I have the following code...

```
runNow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

    final Search s = (Search) node.getUserObject();

    // Swing worker
    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            s.run();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            window.updateResultsPanel(s.getResults(), s.getName());
         }
    };

    worker.run();

    }
});
```

This is a popup menu action which should create a new SwingWorker, free up the GUI, do some work, then update the results of the window. However, right now when I click the menu item the GUI becomes locked up until the work completes which is baffling, the whole point of using a SwingWorker is so that won't happen.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

-Cody

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be calling [`SwingWorker#execute`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute%28%29) to start the worker, not `run`

Run is exposed by the `Runnable` interface, but execute actually schedules the worker to run at some time in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Have to change method `SwingWorker.run()` to `SwingWorker.execute()` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Use the 'add comments' to reply to someone, and they get a notification. I suggest doing a delete this 'answer'.

Comment: @Tinman users with reputations less than 50pts cant post comments everywhere, but answers is (even quite newbee..) correct

Comment: @mKorbel then he has motivation to get higher rep :)

Comment: Seriously guys? I figured out the answer on my own and decided to share it instead of taking the question down. Personally I could give a rats behind about rep...